# 'Have you been crying' or 'have you cried'?

Tags: present-perfect, progressive-aspect

I know that the present perfect suggests that something happened a short time ago, like

> I have just arrived home.

but I read on the Internet that the present perfect continuous refers to the same thing. The example is

> Why is your eyes red? Have you been crying?

So, what's the difference between "Have you been crying?" and "Have you cried?"

Please, if you see any grammatical mistakes, let me know about it.

Comment: Present perfect is "I have cried." Present perfect _progressive/continuous_ is "I have been crying." Present perfect emphasizes the completion of the action, while present perfect progressive emphasizes the duration.

Comment: It should be "Why *are* your eyes red?"

Comment: When someone asks, "Have you cried?" they are assuming that the people being asked never cried before